# Select left in zend

Tags: sql, zend-framework, zend-db

How to do something like this in zend:

```
SELECT LEFT(log_browser, LOCATE(' ', log_browser)) AS browser, COUNT(*) AS amount
FROM logs
GROUP BY LEFT(log_browser, LOCATE(' ', log_browser))
```

Answer (score 0):

try :
    $select->from($name, $column)->group()

```
$select->from("logs", array("LEFT(log_browser, LOCATE(' ', log_browser))" => "browser" ,"count(*)" => "amount"))
       ->group(array("LEFT(log_browser, LOCATE(' ', log_browser)");
```

more info how how this works
http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.select.html#zend.db.select.building.group

Dins

Answer (score 0):

Use Zend_Db_Expr class for expressions statements:

```
$browserExpr = new Zend_Db_Expr('LEFT(log_browser, LOCATE(" ", log_browser))');
$select->from("logs", array('browser' => $browserExpr))->group($browserExpr);
```